# Recycling a flashlight

Tags: led, batteries, resistors

I am "another one of those" :) with some understanding but lacking knowledge. I can identify components, know what they are for and even change them when they are visually burn or broken.
So what brings me to your wisdom is the resistor I need for this project. Its a Ryobi flashlight that burned the bulb. I like its form factor and would like to convert it to LED. I have these 3 5mm and 1 11mm laying around for some time. For what I understand the white ones are usually 3.6v and can hold up to 4v (the label on the smaller ones states even less then that), so even if I put them in series it would be 16v and the battery have 18v nominal, peak on a top charged exceeds 20v at no load.
Can someone tell me what would be the appropriate resistor to use (W & Ohms)? I have the Ryobi batts on 2, 4 and 6 Amps.
Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The equation is (Vsupply - Vf)/If, which works out to 668 ohms (20-3.3)/0.025.  The next-higher 5% standard resistor value is 680 ohms but you're dissipating almost half a watt in the resistor.  They do make LED replacements that have the same base as the original bulb and have the chip at the correct position for the reflector to work, in case you weren't looking for a science project.

Comment: Thank you Vir, so you used the no load value of 20v instead of the nominal 18v, is this the normal way to do it or is it a safest way?
I've just found the data for the big one 

Symbol  Parameter  Conditions  Min  Typ  Max  Units

Vf F Volt  Vcc=Min, Ii=-20mA  2.8  3.3  3.8  V

Vr Rev Volt  Vcc=Min, Ioh=MAX, Vil=MAX        5.0 V

Ir  Rev Current  Vr=5V    10µA

If Max DC F Current Vcc=Min, Iol=MAX, Vih=MAX      25  mA

Ipeak Peak DC F Current  Vcc=Min, Iol=MAX, ih=MAX   100  mA

Pd  Max Pwr Dissipation  Vcc=Max, Vi=5.5V        100  mW

So I guess its the same as the small ones

Comment: I live in Brazil and it is not easy to get components and I had these ones here. I looked for it from China but could not find an 18v version.

Comment: Yes, with LEDs, it's safer to use the most conservative values with a series resistor (highest supply voltage, lowest Vf, average If, etc) since too little current will only cause a very slight drop in brightness while too much current can quickly destroy the LED.  Also remember that if you're using 5% resistors, the 680 ohm resistor could be as low as 646 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIFtDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Four white LEDs in series should be drive-able from a 16V battery, leaving about 3 or 4 volts to be dropped by something else - in this case Q1,Q2,R1 (a current sink). The current sink limits LED current to about 25 mA, set by R1...

- \$Current = {0.67 \over R_1}\$

Since one or more of your LEDs is designed for 25mA, current must be limited to this value - even though one of the other 3 LEDs might be able to take more.

What happens when you fully charge the battery to 20V?
The transistors *still limit current* to 25 mA, and run a little warmer because they soak up more than 3 or 4 volts of the higher battery voltage. Q1 may run a little warm, but should stay below 50C. These NPN transistors are not very critical - many others NPN types should be acceptable. R2 is not critical - 10k would be fine.

---

While these LEDs use battery current far more efficiently than an incandescent bulb, the optical design may give you disappointing results. That big reflector won't direct much light in the desired direction, since the LED resin lens will dominate. That reflector is designed for an isotropic light source (equal light in all directions).

It seems a waste to use such a big battery (2, 4, or 6Amps) to drive small 0.025 Amp LEDs.
If you replaced these four white LEDs with four able to take more current (for brighter light), then Q1 should be replaced with a larger transistor that can dissipate more heat. R1 would become a smaller-value resistor.

Answer (score 0):

So you want an LED work light?  That's one of my pet projects so I'll put some info here for you:  The LEDs you have will fill you with disappointment.  You should invest a few dollars in a single high power LED.  You really like your flashlight, so if you're going to upgrade it at all you may as well make it worth your time.

I'd splurge on a CREE XP-G3 LED, preferably pre mounted on a copper PCB (aluminum will do).  It'll cost about 5 currency units plus shipping.  Then you need to figure out how much space you have to work with in the flashlight and how large of a heatsink you can fit in to help out the MCPCB.

The LED is rated for 6W max, but for efficiency, longevity, and the fact that your plastic case will keep heat in to some degree, you should probably give your light multiple power modes or a dimmer.  You can shop around for cheaper LED current drivers, but the one I'm fond of for good efficiency, small form factor and decent output current is Luxeon's BuckPuck.  The other big advantage of it is it's fairly idiot proof and easy to set up with a voltage reference or PWM dimmer.  They only go up to 1A, which will put an XP-G3 at about 2.875W and respectable efficiency, which based on my experience, should outperform the original bulb by a significant margin even at half power.  For these, you're looking at around 10-15 currency units plus shipping.  The nice thing about this driver is should you decide you want an even more powerful light down the road, you can select a high power LED with a higher voltage and total power (your tool batteries give you lots of headroom and if the original bulb was 6W for example, you can likely get away with a similar wattage LED).  With an 18V nominal battery, the BuckPuck can happily power 12V or more of LEDs at 1A.

One advantage of going with a more powerful LED off the bat is that LED efficiency increases when they are underpowered, so you can compare against a CREE XHP70 if you like, a 12V 1A (12W) LED that you can get for a similar price to the XP-G3. It has a slightly larger lens to match your parabolic reflector better and give you better beam shape.  At a max power of 12W, it still won't make a power tool battery sweat, but there might be some concern of overheating, resulting in you setting it up so it's maximum wattage was some lower number (could be determined experimentally).  If you set it up, for example, for 6W max and then dimmed it down to 2.85W to match the XP-G3 power, you may get better luminous efficacy than with the XP-G3, although the XP-G3 is one generation newer and has higher (~210 vs ~180) luminous efficacy at rated current.

I'm recommending CREE and Luxeon because I know these LEDs well and I know they are high end.  I can't guarantee they are the absolute best.  There are other high end brands with high power high luminous efficacy LEDs you could check out as well as a wide variety of knockoffs.  Shop around, but favor product with datasheets available.  Same goes for the Luxeon Buckpuck.  It's been around for ages, so you can likely find a wide variety of similar products by now, although I've never gone looking.

If you follow this advice you should be able to set up a reliable, much higher powered worklight without a lot of trouble or engineering skill.  If you decide to make it dimmable, you might need a bit more help to interpret the datasheet and set it up that way.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are awesome! I've decided to go KISS on this one and order the direct replacement
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32905012786.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.7f7a4c4dO42Uqh
but i did learn a few things with your replies.